# 'Click Element' Built-In Variable always returns the same as 'Click URL'

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use the Built-In "Click Element" Variable in Google Tag Manager v2, but am getting strange results.

When I take a look at the variable data coming through when debug mode, I'm only getting the URL that's used in the href attribute, not a DOM element as expected.

Has anyone else seen this?

[image: GTM Debugger Output]

Comment: "Click Element" type is object and "Click URL" is a string.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that but I'm not sure how that helps me get the value out of it that I want.

Comment: In the console, when the element in question is clicked, you can go into the Dev console and check the gtm.click object. From there you can see which property of the clicked element to use. For example, you can get the clicked elements URL, classes, text, parent classes, child classes, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part.  What is missing is the ability to get a reference to the DOM element that was clicked.  I had thought that I would get some reference from which I could perform other actions on the element (e.g. look up an attribute value).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you are trying access the DOM element that was clicked, you can do so by inspecting  the click event that was associated with the element in question. There you will find the reference to the gtm.element object. You can access probably everything you need from there. For example, if you need to get a data attribute, you can create a Data Layer variable in GTM with the value of "gtm.element.attribute.name_of_your_attribute". Does that help?